# Python selenium xpath, having trouble properly copying/saving html and text within a specific class element

Tags: python

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4bRZ.png

Trying to examine a webpage through python selenium xpath, the page has twenty elements labeled, `"lh-copy truncate silver"`, I need the information within the class elements, both the `'link i need'` and `'info I need'` to be saved. However when I run my code, the results that it gives me just says `"None"` twenty times which is the amount this class element appears on the page.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
generic_variable = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="lh-copy truncate silver"]')

#for ii in generic_variable:
    #print(ii.get_attribute('inner_html'))
```

Here are the results that it prints out twenty times:

```
None
```

**Edit:** Some of you are asking for an error message, there isn't an error message. It prints `'None'` 20 times which is the exact number of times this element appears on the page, so it does know the element is there just isn't pulling the data from the element.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: always put code, data and error messge as text (not image) in question (not in comment)

Comment: in question (not in comment) you should add url to this page so we could see its HTML.

Comment: shouldn't be `innerHTML` instead of  `inner_html` ?

Comment: Edit: Some of you are asking for an error message, there isn't an error message. It prints 'None' 20 times which is the exact number of times this element appears on the page, so it does know the element is there just isn't pulling the data from the element.

Comment: it is natural reaction when we see new user and unformatted code, image with code, etc. :)

Comment: I couldn't test it with your code and url but I sure your problem is `inner_html`. You have to use `innerHTML` instead of `inner_html` to get text instead of `None`

Comment: innerHTML causes the same issue

Comment: it is strange because I get text/html when I test it with other page. Maybe create minimal working code so we could run it and test this problem.

Comment: BTW: to get link better use xpath to find `<a>` inside `ii` and then use `get_attribute('href')`. To get text use xpath to find `<span>` inside `ii` and then get `.text`. ie. `ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//a')[0].get_attribute('href')`

Comment: I messed up, you were right,when I saw you write "innerHTML" I used "INNERhtml" instead and that wasn't working either.  When I realized my mistake, it worked. Thank you so much!.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you, is there anything that I could for for you?! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: it is too small mistake to create answer for this. But I can add it as answer and then you can mark it as accepted and upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistake in name of attribute `'inner_html'`. It has to be `'innerHTML'` (similar `'outerHTML'`)

```
generic_variable = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="lh-copy truncate silver"]')

for ii in generic_variable:
    print(ii.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

But to get `href` and `text` I would use `ii` with another `xpath` and relative path (`'.//'`)

(and with `find_element_...` without `s` at the end of word `element` - to get only one element)

```
generic_variable = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="lh-copy truncate silver"]')

for ii in generic_variable:

    link = ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href')

    text = ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//span').text

    print(link, text)
```